# Function to check a range of columns for a value then populate found value into a new column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with data spreading across many columns but I want to be able to summarize the data into one column as seen in the first column `School Number` in the screenshot. [Sample Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfKpvHRRb94B6YBJAmrdme3hYfNBNfg5jJlPXzKdvNc/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in A2 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:2), 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 1", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: I made a mistake and realized I have more columns which are hidden and the formula is returning that. The data I want is actually a link with the word "Application". Is there a way to query and check for only column with the word Application?

Comment: `=IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:2), 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col1 contains 'Application' limit 1", 0))`

Comment: or shorter: `=IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:2), "where Col1 contains 'Application' limit 1", 0))`